# UIWebView displaying as a white screen

Tags: ios, uiwebview

In my app, I have a view controller  that contains a UIWebView. This View Controller has the UIWebView as an IBOutlet. When loading the view I just get a white screen with my navigation bar at the top. Here is the code for loading the UIWebView. Originally my completeURL wasn't being formatted correctly and was just null. No information I can scour through online seems to be able to help me with this issue.

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=%@", _URL];
    NSURL *completeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:completeURL];
    [_webView loadRequest:request];
    NSLog(@"%@", request);
}
```

Comment: It is a property of the View Controller passed to it by the preceeding view, which when combined with www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term= forms a legitimate URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

once check this line may be problem is here replace this once and check it,

```
NSString *stringURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed?term=%@", _URL];
```

Comment: wer is the problem? ... please describe !

Comment: pubmed/?term here remove / ,then may be it'l work but not sure.

Comment: I checked on one and I got "www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/?term=21452241, 21452247, 21830221"which isn't a valid web address...but completeURL is I believe

Comment: Yep, completeURL is fine. I even tried feeding it a obviously fine URL like www.google.com, but still I only see white

Comment: You're right! Wow, I can't believe I overlooked something so simple. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem could be in:

```
NSURL *completeURL = [NSURL URLWithString: [stringURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
```

check intermediate strings

Comment: Nope, this checks out perfectly fine

Comment: Then why u getting nil there dude?

Comment: I did before I adding the stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, it didn't like the spaces in my string. Turns out I just forgot the http://, thanks for your help though